# how to: ´postMessage´ can it send two messages?

Tags: javascript, postmessage, worker

is it possible to send two messages with 1 postMessage() from a worker.js?
and us the two messages in two different places.

etc

```
w.onmessage = function (event) {
document.getElementById(event.message 1 here).innerHTML=event.message 2 here;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually postMessage can post not only String, but any Object, e.g.

```
 myWorker.postMessage({
     m1: 'msg1',
     m2: 'msg2'
 });
```

And in your worker:

```
 onmessage = function (event) {
     //will be msg1
     console.log(event.data.m1);

     //will be msg2
     console.log(event.data.m2);
 };
```